# ASP.Net Templated Server Controls difference between UpdatePanel and other controls

Tags: asp.net, templates, updatepanel, servercontrols

Using the advise given on this post...

[Creating an ASP.Net Templated Server control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908260/creating-an-asp-net-templated-server-control)

... I was able to create a nice templated server control.

However, what I noticed is that on some templated controls such as the ASP.Net UpdatePanel you dont need to use FindControl to find the actual control inside your template. UpdatePanel has a  template (or similar) and this just allows dirrect access to your controls without using the FindControl method that I have to use on the templated control I have created.

How do I make my control like the update panel where no template is needed?

Thanks.

Comment: This blog entry finally solved the problem: http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/05/31/use-templateinstance-single-to-avoid-findcontrols.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a template, but add [TemplateInstance(TemplateInstance.Single)] to the property with the ITemplate and that should solve that issue:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.templateinstanceattribute.aspx

HTH.